# Two logins (on different service providers) on one jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, xmpp, smack

I have written a code that logs in on one service provider through XMPP connection.

I have a button which when clicked should allow me to create another XMPPConnection object and display both roster lists (of both service providers) on one page. That is the previous connection should not be disconnected.

I am using JSP since I am making use of the Smack Library. Any suggestions on how I can go about with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can log in two users via same connection. Make connection object Global and then try.